# how to scroll android button along with the listview content

Tags: android

i'm developing android app which requires listview with the bottom android button.. button need to scroll along with listview content, not fixed to end of the screen.

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/requestlist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Save"
                style="@style/btn_white_large"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Customise your Listview Adapter Item or use linearlayout inside scrollview andadd items dynamicall in linearlayout.

Comment: can u please suggest any links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u put LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView? It will scroll together.

Answer (score 3):

You can place this button in a different xml file and inflate that xml in a view.
And then try using listview.addFooter(view)

Also remove scroll view from this layout